# Why is allocating a byte array throwing an Overflow exception?

Tags: c#

I am receiving an error on my C# Console Application. I am trying to do some code but its throwing an exception whenever I do so, not all the time just some of the time, by the way it is not just me using this program there is 30+ members on it using it also.

Code:

```
int MessageLength = Base64Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { data[pos++], data[pos++], data[pos++] });
int MessageId = Base64Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { data[pos++], data[pos++] });

byte[] Content = new byte[MessageLength - 2];
```

The Exception is:

> Exception logged 1/23/2015 10:54:54 AM in packet handling:
>   System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow.

The exception is happening on line 37, the following line...

```
byte[] Content = new byte[MessageLength - 2];
```

Here is a image of the lengths changing of 'pos' and 'MessgaeLength'
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `MessageLength`?

Comment: And the value from `pos`?

Comment: I will run some code to check, ill reply with the length in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `MessageLength > 2`.

For example :

```
if (MessageLength < 3)
    throw new Exception("Incorrect MessageLength");
```

Otherwise, you are trying to instantiate an array with Length 0 / -X.

Comment: 0 is an ok value, it might not be logical in this context, but you can certainly construct an array with a length of 0 in .NET.

Comment: I choose this method and it has stopped the exceptions so far, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably in the length of `MessageLength`. If the length is less than 2, you will get an overflow.

Try this failing code:

```
int x = 0;
byte[] Content = new byte[x - 2];
```

You should check before allocating that `x-2` is more than or equals to 0:

```
if (MessageLength >= 2)
{
    byte[] Content = new byte[MessageLength - 2];

    ...
}
```